# Strange groupby behaviour in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

Let's suppose to have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a','b','b','c','c'], 'x': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

This dataframe:

```
  key  x
0   a  1
1   b  2
2   b  3
3   c  4
4   c  5
```

has one 'a' row, two 'b' rows and two 'c' rows.
Now if I group the dataframe by `key` column and apply a function `f` printing out the name of each grouped dataframe I have:

```
df.groupby('key').apply(lambda x: print(x.name))
```

with this output:

```
a
a
b
c
Out[71]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

why there are **two** prints of **a**?

Note my pandas version is 0.20.1

```
pd.__version__
Out[72]: '0.20.1'
```

Comment: **two** or **three**?

Comment: No answer but workaround - `df.groupby('key').x.apply(lambda x: print(x.name))`